# Web scrapping by using google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to scrap datas from this website on google sheets. I have an error saying *imported content is empty* by using this syntax :

```
=IMPORTXML("https://lokia.zohorecruit.com/jobs/Careers";"//*[@id='website_block_jobs']/career-website-job-layout3/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/h3/a")
```

I would like to scrap only the title of the function (in one column) and the date in another column.

What is not correct with my synthax ? Can you help me please

Answer (score 1):

in this case, there is no correct syntax. JavaScript elements are not supported by any IMPORT formula of google sheets. you can always backcheck it if you disable JS for a given site and see if there is anything left to be scrapped

[image]

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. I'll take a look at it

Comment: Is there a way to scrap data from that website by using importxml (sheets) or it's the same problem enumerated before ? https://www.quebecemploi.gouv.qc.ca/plateforme-emploi/?lang=fr

Comment: @LePirateNoir no. as mentioned in answer "any IMPORTxml formula" will yield no results

Comment: And how do i recognize when it's  Javascripts elements on a website ?

Comment: @LePirateNoir as mentioned in the answer, enter site settings and switch off the JS and reload the website

Comment: U were right. I did it and there is nothing left to scrap. I'm trying to go by using google apps Script. Here is my code : var webURL = "https://www.quebecemploi.gouv.qc.ca/plateforme-emploi/?lang=fr"
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL)
   var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText()); 
  var itemsOfInterest = $('.manitouTable_h0').first()            I'm block from there. Can you tell me what is missing so i can get the city, the date & the description please.

Answer (score 0):

The careers data can be obtained by using Google Apps Script. The data is stored in a hidden field and can be selected using a regular expression. There are pitfalls to this approach and it's probably more advisable to use a standard parser that might be found in Cheerio or JSDOM. Having said that, the code is below:

```
const ENTITY_CODES = {
  "&#x20;": " ",
  "&#x21;":"!",
  "&#x22;":"\"",
  "&#x23;":"#",
  "&#x24;":"$",
  "&#x25;":"%",
  "&#x26;":"&",
  "&#x27;":"'",
  "&#x28;":"(",
  "&#x29;":")",
  "&#x2a;":"*",
  "&#x2b;":"+",
  "&#x2c;":":",
  "&#x2d;":"-",
  "&#x2e;":".",
  "&#x2f;":"/",
  "&#x3a;":":",
  "&#x3b;":";",
  "&#x3c;":"<",
  "&#x3d;":"=",
  "&#x3e;":">",
  "&#x3f;":"?",
  "&#x40;":"@",
  "&#x5b;":"[",
  "&#x5c;":"\\",
  "&#x5d;":"]",
  "&#x5e;":"^",
  "&#x5f;":"_",
  "&#x60;":"`",
  "&#x7b;":"{",
  "&#x7c;":"|",
  "&#x7d;":"}",
  "&#x7e;":"~",
  "&quot;":'"',
  "&amp;":"&",
  "&lt;":"<",
  "&gt;":">"
};

async function getData() {
  const data  = await (await UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://lokia.zohorecruit.com/jobs/Careers')).getContentText();
  const careersMatches = data.match(/value="([^"]*)" id="jobs"/mi);
  let careersData;

  if (careersMatches && careersMatches[1]) {
   careersData = careersMatches[1];
   for (let [entityCode, entityValue] of Object.entries(ENTITY_CODES)) {
     const regex = new RegExp(entityCode, 'gim');
     careersData = careersData.replace(regex, entityValue);
    };
  }
  
  careersData = JSON.parse(careersData);

  return careersData;
}

async function onOpen() {
  const careersData = await getData();
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'll take a look at it. But tell me Is there a way to scrap data from that website by using importxml (sheets) or it's the same problem enumerated before ? quebecemploi.gouv.qc.ca/plateforme-emploi/?lang=fr

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way with importxml.

Comment: I'm trying to go now by using google apps Script. Here is my code : var webURL = "quebecemploi.gouv.qc.ca/plateforme-emploi/?lang=fr" var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webURL) var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText()); var itemsOfInterest = $('.manitouTable_h0').first() I'm block from there. Can you tell me what is missing so i can get the city, the date & the description please.

Comment: I would create a separate ticket for this issue.